# Why does `ldd` and `(gdb) info sharedlibrary` show a different library base address?

Tags: linux, gdb, symbols, libraries

I see three different outputs for where libc should be loaded.

`ldd` shows the loading address of libc at `0xf7e9e000`

```
$ ldd ~/my_tool
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7ffe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7e9e000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x56555000)
```

While gdb tells me it's loaded at `0xf7e96c60`

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0xf7fe1820  0xf7ff805f  Yes (*)     /lib/ld-linux.so.2
0xf7e96c60  0xf7f9643c  Yes (*)     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

And when I manually calculate the base address based on a symbol:

```
(gdb) print system
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0xf7ebb6b0 <system>
```

[image: system offset]

I get this address:

`0xf7ebb6b0-0x003b6b0 = 0xf7e80000`

Why is that so?

```
calculated: 0xf7e80000
gdb:        0xf7e96c60
ldd:        0xf7e9e000
```

Answer (score 9):

### `ldd`

The program `ldd` is wrong for a few reasons.

First, `ldd` is not meant to be accurate for determining load addresses. Use the environment variable `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS`.

Second, `ldd` will never be correct with ASLR enabled as Guntram showed.  You can disable this pretty trivially if you have `sudo` access.

```
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /bin/bash | grep libc
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f44dae1b000)
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /bin/bash | grep libc
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9b35341000)
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /bin/bash | grep libc
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fef18efd000)
$ echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
0
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /bin/bash | grep libc
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffff75e7000)
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /bin/bash | grep libc
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffff75e7000)
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /bin/bash | grep libc
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffff75e7000)
```

You can verify this by starting an instance of bash in the background and inspecting its maps file.

```
$ bash &
[1] 30398
[1]  + 30398 suspended (tty input)  bash                                                                             
$ grep libc /proc/30398/maps | head -n1
7ffff75e7000-7ffff77a2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 525269                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
```

### `info sharedlibrary`

The address reported by `info sharedlibrary` is the address of the `.text` area.

Note that in the particular libc that I have, the .text is at `0x1f4a0`.

```
$ readelf --wide --section-headers /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so | grep text
  [12] .text             PROGBITS        000000000001f4a0 01f4a0 145c23 00  AX  0   0 16
```

In GDB, if we look at the load addresses of `libc`, we see that it is loaded at `0x7ffff7a14000`.  This will change each time the program is run, if ASLR is enabled on the system.  If you run it under GDB, it will also disable ASLR.  Run the command `set disable-randomization off` before running the target and you will observe it change each run.

```
gdb-peda$ info proc mapping
  ...
  0x7ffff7a14000     0x7ffff7bcf000   0x1bb000        0x0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
  0x7ffff7bcf000     0x7ffff7dcf000   0x200000   0x1bb000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
  0x7ffff7dcf000     0x7ffff7dd3000     0x4000   0x1bb000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
  0x7ffff7dd3000     0x7ffff7dd5000     0x2000   0x1bf000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
  ...
```

You can verify this by checking to see if it starts with the ELF header.

```
gdb-peda$ hexdump 0x00007ffff7a14000 4
0x0000 0x00007ffff7a14000 │ 7f 45 4c 46                                      │ .ELF
0x0004 0x00007ffff7a14004
```

If we add the `0x1f4a0` offset from the `.text` area, we get `0x7ffff7a334a0`.

```
gdb-peda$ printf "%p\n",(0x00007ffff7a14000+0x1f4a0)
0x7ffff7a334a0
```

Now if we look at `info sharedlibrary`, we see exactly this address.

```
gdb-peda$ info sharedlibrary libc
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7a334a0  0x00007ffff7b790c3  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

### Extra Tips

In GDB, you should use the `info proc mapping` command to get the base address of a loaded module.

However, this is not available on FreeBSD, since GDB does not support the FreeBSD-specific APIs necessary to get module base addresses.  Instead, you must use the `info proc mapping` command and perform the translation yourself (by subtracting the address of the `.text` section).

Comment: There is no ASLR in my case. The example I posted in the original question are constant each time.

Comment: My answer addresses the issue.  Info sharedlibrary prints the address of the .text area, not the moduel base.

Comment: Ping.  This is answered.  The very tl;dr is at the end.  You want "info proc mapping".

Comment: @ZachRiggle ping, could you add an explanation for why ldd "is not meant to be accurate"? Also, using LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 does not improve the situation: indeed reading from `man ldd`, invoking ldd is *equivalent* to explicitly call the loader with LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS variable set -- so, ldd is not using it. http://pastebin.com/raw/06bQjui5

Comment: @guiscri: Looking back, I'm not sure why I made that statement.  I expect there was a reason, but it's been two years and I've forgotten.  `ldd foo` and `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS foo` should be functionally equivalent.

In either case, you shouldn't rely on it for module addresses.

Answer (score 4):

First, [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) will load the library at a (slightly) different address with each invocation, to help protect against malware. This is why the addresses between `ldd` and `gdb` are different, and why they may be even different each time you run `gdb`.

If i just grep for the libc executable segment on my system (64 bit, as i didn't have a 32 bit system handy):

```
$ grep 'r-xp.*libc-2.19' /proc/*/maps|head

/proc/10987/maps:7fe455b72000-7fe455d2d000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
/proc/11880/maps:7f029dc1f000-7f029ddda000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
/proc/11884/maps:7f25a9c25000-7f25a9de0000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
/proc/15715/maps:7ffc713da000-7ffc71595000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
/proc/17705/maps:7fe9db80c000-7fe9db9c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
/proc/18558/maps:7fc248544000-7fc2486ff000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
/proc/20156/maps:7f0f8eb13000-7f0f8ecce000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
/proc/2139/maps:7fba4c097000-7fba4c252000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
/proc/2215/maps:7f934ed76000-7f934ef31000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
/proc/2224/maps:7f064d98f000-7f064db4a000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
```

you see every process maps the same library a bit differently.

Also, when the loader loads a library, it creates several memory segments for it. The segments from the ELF file get read into these shared memory segments, *including some headers*. This is why the code start address isn't identical to the segment start address.

For example, on my system :

```
(gdb) info sharedLibrary
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7a334a0  0x00007ffff7b790c3  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

and

```
cat /proc/26271/maps 
7ffff7a14000-7ffff7bcf000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7ffff7bcf000-7ffff7dcf000 ---p 001bb000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7ffff7dcf000-7ffff7dd3000 r--p 001bb000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7ffff7dd3000-7ffff7dd5000 rw-p 001bf000 08:16 23461990                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
```

so you see the memory map for the code segment (the one that is executable, i.e. has the x bit set) ranges from 7ffff7a14000-7ffff7bcf000, but the region the actual code is loaded to is just the subset 7ffff7a334a0-7ffff7b790c3.

You can find a more thorough explanation [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries).

Comment: There is no ASLR in my case. The example I posted in the original question are constant each time.